# How to generate one sprite from many folders using Compass?

Tags: css, compass-sass, sass

I have one folder containing images which also has a subfolder with images. I need to generate just one sprite, not two as happens now, and I also want to control the generated classes depending on the folder/subfolder:

```
@import "mobile/*.png";
@import "mobile/icons/*.png";
```

How can I make compass generate just one sprite?

Answer (score 4):

Up to Compass 0.12.1 you can use this:

```
@import "mobile/**/*.png";
```

Regression may be appeared with version 0.12.2, preventing this syntax to work. Instead, you can browse a list of directories:

```
@import "mobile/{,icons}/*.png";
```

Be sure to start the list with a comma in order to target the current directory `mobile`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post the source, where this feature have been documented?

Comment: What will happen with the same names?

Comment: @a.s.panchenko this feature no longer works now (my answer is 1,5 old). You have to use the [sass-globbing](https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass-globbing) gem.